# How to use Echo in Angular + Laravel?

Tags: angular, laravel, websocket, echo, pusher

I found the Push-Js and apply it in Angular...

But don't know how to use it in Laravel?

Like Angular make a get request then going into Larave's API routes

But what's next? I can't input any code in controller to trigger Echo.join

Comment: This may help you .. https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application

Comment: @VikashPathak Thanks for your comment first! The aim for me to use channel is want to create a Websocket so that I can upload the file through Angular to Laravel and overcome the problem of function loading over-time. Is it this example can help me overcome this problem?

Comment: So you have two different application... and you are using laravel as API correct? Also is there any package you are using?

Comment: @VikashPathak Yes, Angular as Front-end. Laravel as Back-end. Since the Laravel takes about 10 minutes to run the function and return the result to Angular, someone told me Websocket would be a way to solve this problem. Angular uses websocket to keep communicating with Laravel until the job is done. That's why I am trying to do it.